# each user having category with their name and can add sub categories post in that category

Tags: posts, categories, users, user-roles, user-access

I am looking for help or plugin for the following conditions of my site

I am using wordpress 3.0+ version.
 my site is about School where students will get register and post their experience and share knowledge.

**User Registration:**

Once the user is created automatically a new Category should be created with its Reg. ID and user name which will be displayed as below
**mysite.com/jan2345**

**User Blog:**

each user will be able to create new blog which will be the sub category that user's category

for example:
jan wants to post his expedition to Europe so he will create new blog from frontend 
but in backend that will be a category with atleast single post which will be the default post and have default parent category as jan2345. This post url will look like **mysite.com/jan2345/europetour**

**user Page**

User will log in and be able to see only his Blogs and post for edit.

if there is any more suggestions and any way i could do this please reply me

**FYI:** i am not able to use Wordpress multisite functionality bec that creates a 9 new tables so, if there are 1000 users with their site details so there will be more than 9000 tables in database ....

**If there is any other solution where i can create site and that will not increase my tables in data base**

Thank you all in advance

Nikhil J.

Comment: 9 tables per blog? Why? That doesn't happen regularly.

Comment: That's normal behaviour for WPMS, it's adding the default WP table (minus the usertables) for everyblog added.

Comment: **can you confirm my this query :** will shared server database be able to handle the total around 1000 blogs(ie 9000 tables) when school Students are free to register here?

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys

I went thru many forums and other details of the post where i came to conclution to create a simple plugin and will work as below
the algo is divided in different sections

**signup**

when user x is getting registered there will be a category that is created in the name as **x1234** this is the user name and reg. numbers and all the data and sub categories of user x will be dumped in here.

**login section:**

when user is logged in he will not be given any rights of wordpress instead a custom rights are created for each user.
so that they can only see their post to edit

**edit section**

when user creates the blog in the edit section he actually creates category under his Category wiz. **x1234** this category has to have atleast one post. url for the blog will be **mysite.com/x1234/cat_name/post_name**

all users are restricted to modify post or blogs of antother users they can just comment on it